# How to delete image path from list of currently selected photo?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a button to delete the currently viewed image. The image paths are stored in a `List<String>`.
The images appear via `CarouselSlider` from `ImagePicker`.

I've tried to see if I can delete the image via a hardcoded index with `.removeAt()` and that works but again, can't figure how to get current image

What is right way to grab the current index of the on screen image? I've tried with single images and it works find but getting the current index of the currently viewed photo is where I'm running into trouble.

This is how I am getting my Images:

```
 List<String> pickedImageList = [];
  final imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  Future pickImage() async {
    final userPickedImages = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage();
    for (var image in userPickedImages!) {
      pickedImageList.add(image.path);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

This is how I am showing the images. Button to delete currently selected photo is at the bottom with generic function:

```
Column(
  children: [
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: pickImage,
        child: const Text('Add another image')),
    CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        // height: 200,
        viewportFraction: .9,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
      ),
      items: pickedImageList
          .map(
            (item) => SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    item,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                  )),
            ),
            // color: Colors.green,
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            removeImage();
          });
        },
        child: const Text('Remove'))
  ],
),
```

All of the delete buttons that people have solved on SO all involve single images which is not the problem.

I thought maybe a GestureDetector counting up and down with left and right swipes, resetting the counter when it reaches the length of the list. Negatives would be multiplied by it self to get current index usable.